# Convert multiple rows into one rows in a delimiter txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, python3

I have input file like below

```
ID~NAME~CREATED_DATE~NOTES~LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
"12345"~"abc"~"9/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"new patiant"~"9/7/2022 11:52:18 AM"
"25451"~"bdc"~"11/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"next 
month 
visit"~"11/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"
"45522"~"xyz"~"1/8/2022 11:05:18 AM"~"new visiting patient"~"1/8/2022 11:05:18 AM"
"52447"~"pqr"~"5/5/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"transferred
back 
to 
hospital"~"5/5/2022 10:05:18 AM"
"24541"~"rds"~"4/5/2022 05:05:18 AM"~"new patient"~"4/5/2022 05:05:18 AM"
```

below is my my desired output:

```
ID~NAME~CREATED_DATE~NOTES~LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
"12345"~"abc"~"9/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"new patiant"~"9/7/2022 11:52:18 AM"
"25451"~"bdc"~"11/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"next month visit"~"11/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"
"45522"~"xyz"~"1/8/2022 11:05:18 AM"~"transferred back to hospital"~"1/8/2022 11:05:18 AM"
"52447"~"pqr"~"5/5/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"new visiting patient"~"5/5/2022 10:05:18 AM"
"24541"~"rds"~"4/5/2022 05:05:18 AM"~"new patient"~"4/5/2022 05:05:18 AM"
```

please help !

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='([^~]+~){4}[^~]+\n' '{print gensub(/[[:space:]]+/," ","g",RT)}' file
ID~NAME~CREATED_DATE~NOTES~LAST_MODIFIED_DATE
"12345"~"abc"~"9/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"new patiant"~"9/7/2022 11:52:18 AM"
"25451"~"bdc"~"11/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"next month visit"~"11/7/2022 10:05:18 AM"
"45522"~"xyz"~"1/8/2022 11:05:18 AM"~"new visiting patient"~"1/8/2022 11:05:18 AM"
"52447"~"pqr"~"5/5/2022 10:05:18 AM"~"transferred back to hospital"~"5/5/2022 10:05:18 AM"
"24541"~"rds"~"4/5/2022 05:05:18 AM"~"new patient"~"4/5/2022 05:05:18 AM"
```

Comment: HI Ed, thanks for the quick reply. I tried your code but getting error : awk: 0602-553 Function gensub is not defined.
 The input line number is 1.
 The source line number is 1.

Comment: A I said "Using **GNU awk**....". You aren't using GNU awk.